# Perl merging results of maps

Tags: list, perl, dictionary

How do I concatenate the output of two maps to form a single flat array?

I was attempting to use this:

```pl
my $test = { 'foo' => [
    map { 
        { 'i' => "$_" } 
    } 0..1,
    map {
        { 'j' => "$_" }
    } 0..1
] };
```

To achieve the result of this:

```pl
my $test = {'foo' => [
        {
            'i' => '0'
        },
        {
            'i' => '1'
        },
        {
            'j' => '0'
        },
        {
            'j' => '1'
        },
    ]}
```

However, this is what I got in `$test` instead:

```pl
{
    'foo' => [
        {
            'i' => '0'
        },
        {
            'i' => '1'
        },
        {
            'i' => 'HASH(0x7f90ad19cd30)'
        },
        {
            'i' => 'HASH(0x7f90ae200908)'
        }
    ]
};
```

Looks like the result of the second `map` gets iterated over by the first `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list returned by the second `map` is a part of the input list for the first one, following `0..1,`.

The parenthesis can fix that

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dump;

my $test = { 
    'foo' => [ 
        ( map { { i => $_ } } 0..1 ),
        ( map { { j => $_ } } 0..1 )
    ],  
};

dd($test);
```

since they delimit the expression so now the first `map` takes only `0..1` as its input list and computes and returns a list, which is then merged with the second `map`'s returned list.  (Strictly speaking you need parenthesis only around the first `map`.)

This prints

```
{ foo => [{ i => 0 }, { i => 1 }, { j => 0 }, { j => 1 }] }
```

I've removed unneeded quotes, please restore them if/as needed in your application.

Without parenthesis the `map` after the comma is taken to be a part of the expression generating the input list for the first `map`, so producing the next element(s) of the input list after `0..1`, effectively

```
map { i => $_ } (0..1, LIST);
```

Consider

```
my @arr = (
    map { { 'i', $_ } } 
        0..1, 
        qw(a b),
        map { ( { 'j', $_ } ) } 0..1
);
dd(\@arr);
```

It prints

```
[
  { i => 0 },
  { i => 1 },
  { i => "a" },
  { i => "b" },
  { i => { j => 0 } },
  { i => { j => 1 } },
]
```

This is also seen from your output, where all keys are `i` (no `j`s).